# Why is it (allegedly) dangerous to feed ducks with breadcrumbs and pieces of bread?

Tags: biochemistry, zoology, food, ornithology, nutrition

I used to go down to the local lake all the time with leftover bread and throw little pieces of it to the hungry duckies, who very eagerly fetched it and ate it while happily quacking away.

I thought I was doing them a favour, but apparently, it's bad for them? Can even kill them?

Is this *really* true, or is this a false rumor spread by people who don't like ducks and want to deprive them of their favourite food?

Why exactly would bread, especially soaked in water, somehow damage wild ducks? Isn't it a very neutral food which feels filling and nice for the ducks? Nobody says that they *have* to *only* eat bread thrown from humans -- they can still eat little insects and algae in the lake or whatever they normally/naturally eat.

What exactly can happen? I never noticed any dead ducks or ducks in pain whenever I visited them. They seemed to love the bread and consider it a luxury dish from a fine restaurant from their perspective.

Comment: This web page from National Geographic can give you some idea: https://blog.education.nationalgeographic.org/2017/03/27/stop-feeding-ducks-bread/
Also, you can give a look to this page from the Wildlife center of Viginia:
https://www.wildlifecenter.org/problem-feeding-ducks

Comment: This question was [asked and answered on Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/43742/37236).

Comment: the simple answer to this is white bread is carbohydrate(sugar)and not a lot more so it causes malnutition.